# TypeError: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a list of tasks that I'd like to get minus the ones I've already allocated.  I'm passing in a list and it's giving me an error:

> TypeError: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

I tested passing in a single integer and it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Code below:

```
# models/task.py:
@classmethod
def find_unallocated_tasks(cls, task_ids):
return cls.query.filter_by(
    (id != _id).all() for _id in task_ids)


# resources/task.py:
class UnallocatedTasks(Resource):
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('allocated_task_ids')
def get(self):
    data = UnallocatedTasks.parser.parse_args()
    id_list = data["allocated_task_ids"].split(",")
TaskModel.find_unallocated_tasks(id_list)
```

postman (GET):

```
{"allocated_task_ids": "1,2,3"}
```

Answer (score 2):

That isn't how you filter by a list in SQLAlchemy.

I'm not that familiar with the query syntax, but I suspect you need to use `filter` rather than `filter_by`, and the `.in_` operator.

```
return cls.query.filter(~cls.id.in_(task_ids))
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
Make a object of TaskModel class i.e.
task_model_obj = TaskModel()
task_model_obj.find_unallocated_tasks(id_list)
```